# 7za command line from java process builder

Tags: java, docker, 7zip

I have a Docker container where the base image is Corretto 17. I have also installed p7zip in the image using 'yum install -y p7zip'. Additionally, I created a user, switched to that user, and copied my Spring Boot JAR file to the Docker image. Currently, I'm running this Docker container in an AWS ECS Fargate cluster, and I'm encountering an issue when trying to execute the '7za' command line using Process Builder.

Below is the cmd I'm trying to run.

```
7za a -ptest123 /data/app/encrypted/test.7z /data/app/files/test.txt
```

But when I run the above cmd the 7za is trying to open the archive test.7z which is not supposed to. It should create the archive with the file test.txt. Below is the error log.

```
2023-05-16T10:28:08.440-06:00    7-Zip (a) [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
2023-05-16T10:28:08.440-06:00    p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=C.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,2 CPUs Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2666 v3 @ 2.90GHz (306F2),ASM,AES-NI)
2023-05-16T10:28:08.440-06:00    Open archive: /data/app/encrypted/test.7z
2023-05-16T10:28:08.440-06:00    ERROR: /data/app/encrypted/test.7z
2023-05-16T10:28:08.440-06:00    /data/app/encrypted/test.7z
2023-05-16T10:28:08.440-06:00    Open ERROR: Can not open the file as [7z] archive
2023-05-16T10:28:08.440-06:00    ERRORS:
2023-05-16T10:28:08.440-06:00    Is not archive
2023-05-16T10:28:08.440-06:00    System ERROR:
2023-05-16T10:28:08.440-06:00    Operation not permitted
2023-05-16T10:28:08.440-06:00    Exit Code: 2
```

below is the code im using

```
    private static synchronized void linuxCmd(String cmd) {
        try {
            // Create a ProcessBuilder for the command
            ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(cmd.split("\\s+"));

            // Merge error stream with output stream
            processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);

            // Start the process
            Process process = processBuilder.start();

            // Read the output of the process
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                output.append(line).append("\n");
            }

            // Wait for the process to finish
            int exitCode = process.waitFor();

            // Print the output and exit code
            System.out.println("Output:\n" + output.toString());
            System.out.println("Exit Code: " + exitCode);
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

i will be calling the above method with the 7za cmd i provided earlier

I have tried the same from docker file. i have created file written the same cmd in docker file and executed it while building the image. it worked properly.

```
Step 16/19 : RUN 7za a -ptest123 /data/app/encrypted/test.7z /data/app/files/test.txt
 ---> Running in 44786d829af4

7-Zip (a) [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=C.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,2 CPUs AMD PRO A8-8600B R6, 10 Compute Cores 4C+6G     (660F01),ASM,AES-NI)

Scanning the drive:
1 file, 15457 bytes (16 KiB)

Creating archive: /data/app/encrypted/test.7z

Items to compress: 1


Files read from disk: 1
Archive size: 2690 bytes (3 KiB)
Everything is Ok
Removing intermediate container 44786d829af4
 ---> 10ab11bb503c
```

Comment: Does it work when execute the same command from the command line? What is the output of `cmd.split("\\s+")`?

Comment: Use [code format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for logs, not quote format. Quote is for human text, not logs and other pre formatted text. Quote breaks the existing format of the log, makes it very hard to read and gets in the way of trying to copy text for investigation.

Comment: Just FYI: You don't need to use external tools to create ZIP files in Java. It comes with classes for handling ZIP files. See for example https://www.baeldung.com/java-compress-and-uncompress

Comment: @aled the `cmd.split("\\s+")` output will be as follows `ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("7za", "a", "-ptest123", "/data01/cfm/encrypted/test.7z", "/data01/cfm/files/test.txt");`

Comment: Does it work when you execute the same command from the command line?

Comment: @RoToRa 7zip files are not supported by the ZIP functionality in Java.

Comment: @RoToRa yes but in don't think so it can compress with password protect. i have tried compressing using zip classes and then encryption it with aes256 algo. but after that when i try to open that archive in 7zip windows app its not opening properly, i have a specific use case where i need to compress with password through program and sent it to users where they will decompress in there windows machine using 7zip application.

Comment: @aled i tested in cmd line during docker build and add the output in the body, please check. since its a ecs fargate container i dont have full control over to connect and run the cmd. so i ran it during docker build

Comment: Strictly speaking, unless you add `processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);` you haven't shown the error log, just standard output. The error log might - or not - tell you what happened.

Comment: @DuncG i have added processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true); updated the code and error log above. i still dont know why its trying to open test.7z as archive.

Comment: "Operation is not permitted" is a very specific error. Look at your file permissions.

Comment: (You might also think of making Java run `strace -f -o /path/to/log.strace -s 2048 7z ...` and comparing `log.strace` generated that way with the `log.strace` you get from running the same command with no JVM involved; if the JVM really _is_ doing something different, like injecting whitespace or special characters in the environment, or setting you up with a materially different set of environment variables, or whatever else... you'll be able to see it there).

Comment: You might also verify read before the call: `System.out.println("size="+Files.readAllBytes(Path.of("/data/app/encrypted/test.7z")).length);`